# create mysql odbc connection through batch script

Tags: mysql, programming-languages, odbc

Is there anyway to create a System DSN enter for MYSQL database (windows OS), with silent installation of MySQL ODBC Drivers programatically either through batch script or any other language?

If drivers installation is not possible , atleast automatic DSN entery would be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, run `odbcconf.exe` with appropriate parameters. For example

```
ODBCConf ConfigSysDSN "SQL Server" "DSN=LocalODBCConnection|SERVER=(local)"
```

for MySQL

```
ODBCConf ConfigSysDSN "MySQL" "DSN=LocalODBCConnection|SERVER=MySQL_ServerName"
```

Comment: I tried to run ODBCConf with specified parameters, but it says component not found in the registry.

Comment: solved, I had to keep MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver in place of MySQL

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim ad
ad = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")      'create and open ODBC connection 
ad.ConnectionString = ("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=localhost;Database=db;UID=root;PWD=xxxxxx;option=3")
ad.Open()
```