# Portable ODBC connection driver

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc, database-connection

Is there any availability to make MySQL ODBC connection driver portable? I develop an application which uses MySQL ODBC ocnnection driver with `TADOConnection` and everything is working properly on developer's machine, there ODBC connection driver is installed. When I run this application on another machine (no ODBC driver installed) an error raises. Is there any opportunity to include necessary libs to program and make the project independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bundle the MySQL ODBC driver with your installer (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-windows.html), but remember that if you're using the free GPL connector you're bound to the GPL, thereby or you release your application (and code) under the GPL as well, or you're violating the MySQL GPL license. To avoid it, you can always buy a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC needs a driver since it is an API abstraction over existing database access libraries - see [How to explain why ODBC requires a database driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040338/how-to-explain-why-odbc-requires-a-database-driver)

Since there is no standard way of installing a database driver, you'll have to rely on the driver instructions, which are specific.

For MySQL, if you launch `setup -r` it would install the ODBC provider silently.

The follow these steps to add your database connection: [create mysql odbc connection through batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792034/create-mysql-odbc-connection-through-batch-script)

Comment: I don't have appropriate connection on computer. I make TADOConnection pbjects on computer run-time and specify connection string also runtime. So is there any way to extract that ODBC libraries to include them to program package?